# Seed Data onto Database in an ruby program using activerecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, seeding

How can I seed some data to an table using active record in an standalone ruby program?

So far my code is:

```
require 'prawn'
require 'active_record'
require 'pg'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'postgresql',
  host:     'localhost',
  database: 'sample',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '...'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :xmldata, force: true do |t|
    t.text :xmlstr
  end
end
```

Comment: my exisiting code is listed at the given link:   http://pastebin.com/f25KQfum

Comment: Share the code in question instead of links to other pasties or gists.

Comment: @Wand Maker I would love to post but sof doesn't allow as i am a beginner and dont have required reputation points to post code or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you create table only if it does not exist:

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
     if not connection.table_exists? :xmldata
       create_table :xmldata, force: true do |t|
         t.text :xmlstr
       end
     end
   end
   ```

   end
2. Create an ActiveRecord model for the table.

   ```
   class Xmldata < ActiveRecord::Base
   end
   ```
3. Create objects and save them

   ```
   Xmldata.create({xmlstr: "<person><name>SOuser</name></person>"})
   ```